# Multi port clonezilla server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, clonezilla

I am doing cloning of multiple computers - all of which are different.

Therefore I can't do multicast - bummer :(

However I can put multiple ethernets into the "server" (more like desktop) so can you have those ports being used as well so that you can increase bandwidth (obviously up to the limit of the drive)?

EDIT:

Okay so I found out that you can do ethernet bonding so that you can have multiple ports being used like one NIC. However, trouble comes when trying to setup clonezilla to use this bond instead of a eth. Is there a way of giving the bond a name (not like Wired Connection 1) like eth0 or eth1 so that it will be recognised by clonezilla?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application will just use the IP stack, which will use its routing table to define how it talks out, if it has a bonded interface in there then it'll just use that, there's nothing to configure in the application.

Comment: Nah it's cool, the bonded port wasn't made properly, so when i got it working, clonezilla saw the bonded port no problem. It is all working now